# Use the definition of infinite limit to prove $\lim_{x \to 1+} \frac{x}{x^2-1}=\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove
>   $$\lim_{x \to 1+} \frac{x}{x^2-1}=\infty$$

And I was given the solution like this: but I could not understand how it removes the complicated terms.

Let $\delta=\min(0.5,\frac{1}{5M})$.

$$\frac{x}{x^2-1}=\frac{x}{(x+1)(x-1)}
\geq\frac{0.5}{\left(\frac{1}{5M}\right)(1.5+1)}=5M\times0.2=M$$

I understand the definition of $M-\delta$, but what I don't understand is what is the solution doing, I mean the process of estimation to get rid of the complicated terms. Anyone can enlighten me? thanks!

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: let x be an arbitrary real number such that 1<x<1+δ

Comment: The point is to prove that $\dfrac{x}{x^2-1}$ will be as large as you want (greater than any large $M$) provided that $x-1$ is positive and small enough (ie verifies $\;0<x-1<\delta\,$). $\delta$ is chosen in function of $M$ for this purpose (subtract $1$ and add $1$ in the inequalities and deduce the last line).

Comment: Does "get rid of the complicated terms" refer to finding the equality with $5M \times 0.2$ on the right-hand side? Or is the question how the inequality was derived?

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Erm,if I think like this: first, guess \Delta=0.5 then 0<x-1<0.5 >>>1<x<1.5 >>>>2<x+1<2.5 >>>is it correct? how to continue?

Comment: @user3437854: You thus obtain that $x> 1,\;\dfrac 1{x+1}> \dfrac 1{1+1.5},\;\dfrac 1{x-1}> 0.5$. If you suppose further that $x-1<\delta$ you'll get that $\dfrac 1{x-1}> \dfrac 1{\delta}$ (the fraction should be written $\dfrac{0.5}{(1.5+1)\dfrac{1}{5M}}\,$ or more logically I think $\dfrac{1}{(1.5+1)\dfrac{1}{2.5\,M}}\,$ but $1>0.5\,$ so that the first one is correct if not optimal...). (the $0.5$ superior limit is a 'security' for small values of $M$ but is linked to the $5$ coefficient or $2.5$ in front of $M$).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni is it 1/(x-1)>1/0.5? ur first sentence

Comment: Oups this should be $\dfrac 1{x-1}> \dfrac 1{0.5}$ but this is unimportant since the stronger $\dfrac 1{x-1}> \dfrac 1{\delta}$ is used.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni so the solution should set delta=min(1/2,1/2.5M) right?

Comment: I think yes ($\frac 1{5M}$ is correct too but unneeded I think here). If you replace the value $0.5$ but another value in $(0,1)$ you'll get another constant in front of $M$.

Comment: ya, so it is just a method of estimation right? thanks so much! can you help me to vote ?thx!

Comment: Huh... I can't vote for you! :-). \delta is just chosen such that $\dfrac{1}{(1.5+1)\,\delta}=M\,$ here $\delta=\dfrac{1}{2.5\,M}$ should do the job (with a bound at $0.5$ to avoid division by zero and such things).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni can I ask you some other questions? If I was asked to apply MVT to show something like this: x> sinx > x-x^3/6 for all x>0. Is there any method to know what function f(x) to be used?thx!

Comment: @UnusualSkill: this seems too long for a comment (and the system is complaining.. and I don't understand the $f$ part of the question ;-)). You should ask another question about this I think,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19044/discussion-between-unusualskill-and-raymond-manzoni).

Answer (score 1):

When $M$ is large, it is enough to take $\delta=\frac{1}{2M}$. This is because if we have $\delta=\frac{1}{2M}$ then the numerator is larger than $1$ while the denominator is less than $\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{2M} \right )\frac{1}{2M}$. Hence the quotient is larger than $\frac{2M}{1+\frac{1}{2M}}$. To make this last expression larger than $M$, we need $\frac{1}{2M} \leq 1$, or in other words $M \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

The problem is that we're in control of $\delta$, not $M$, so we can't require $M \geq \frac{1}{2}$. A workaround is to take $\delta = \min \left \{ \frac{1}{2M},1 \right \}$. Then if $M<\frac{1}{2}$ then the numerator is still larger than $1$ and the denominator is still less than 2, so the quotient is still larger than $\frac{1}{2}>M$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for any $A,\ B\neq0,\ C\neq0,$
$$\frac{A}{\left(\frac 1B\right)C} = \frac{1}{\left(\frac 1B\right)} \cdot \frac AC
 = B \cdot \frac{A}{C}.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{0.5}{\left(\frac{1}{5M}\right)(1.5+1)} = 5M \cdot \frac{0.5}{1.5+1}
 = 5M \cdot 0.2.$$

(Assuming the left-hand end of the formula above contains the "complicated terms" that we had to "get rid of".)

Answer (score 0):

Given an $M>0$ somebody found by reverse engineering the proposed $\delta:=\min\left\{0.5,{1\over 5 M}\right\}$ would do the job. Now insert after this definition of $\delta$ the phrase "If $1<x<1+\delta$"; saying that you are only considering points $x$ with  $|x-1|<\delta$ and $x>1$. Then your text could read as follows:

If $1<x<1+\delta$ then $0<x-1<{1\over 5M}$, and $x+1<1.5$. It follows that
$${x\over x^2-1}={x\over(x-1)(x+1)}>{1\over{1\over 5M}\cdot1.5}> M\ .\tag{1}$$
This means that the proposed $\delta$ does exactly what it was set up to do.

Note that, given $M$, such a $\delta>0$ is not determined uniquely, even though people write $\delta(M)$ sometimes. It is experience with such questions that leads us in finding an *admissible* $\delta$. Here are some hints: The factor $x-1$ in the denominator of $(1)$ indicates that ${1\over\delta}$ should have the order of magnitude at least $M$. Since the other factors amount to ${x\over1+x}<1$ some extra measures have to be taken to guarantee $(1)$. Nobody is claiming that the proposed $\delta$ is the "optimal" or "simplest" $\delta=\delta(M)$ doing the job.

Comment: What I don understand is how to find the proposed delta?can you help? thx!

Comment: is there any wrong with the solution? because When i restrict δ=0.5>>>0<x-1<0.5>>>>1<x<1.5 >>>>2<x+1<2.5 >>>   1/2.5<1/(x+1)<1/2    why the numerator is 0.5?

Answer (score 0):

We can first use partial fraction decomposition to $\frac{x}{x^2-1},$ which leads to
\begin{gather*}
\frac{x}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{2(x+1)}+\frac{1}{2(x-1)},
\end{gather*}
which implies that 
\begin{gather*}\tag{1}
\frac{x}{x^2-1}>\frac{1}{2(x-1)}, \qquad \text{provided } x>-1.
\end{gather*}

Let $M>0.$ Set 
$$\delta=\frac{1}{2M}.$$
For every $x>1,$ we have
\begin{align*}
0<x-1<\delta\implies  \frac{x}{x^2-1}&>\frac{1}{2(x-1)}\qquad\qquad \text{by }(1)\\
&>\frac{1}{2\delta}=\frac{1}{2\frac{1}{2M}}=M,
\end{align*}
which, by definition of limit, completes the proof.